# Is it possible to maintain the url while redirecting to a classic asp page from a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp-classic, routes

While migrating a site from a classic asp to MVC, I'm having the problem that not all controllers are implemented yet. For those which are not implemented, I'd like to serve the classic asp page (say /product.asp?id=123) while maintaining the nice url /product/123. To accomplish this I implemented a dummy ProductController which returns a RedirectResult to the classic asp url. But that changes the url in the browsers navigation bar. Requirement has it, that the urls should always be a clean (mvc) one, eventhough the page has not yet been fully migrated.

If this can't be done using a dummy controller, what would be an alternative option to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe Server.TransferRequest might be an option for you - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think two ways to do it:

1. In the product controller, execute the `product.asp?id=123` page and return the HTML using `Return Content(..)`
2. Add a dummy view product and from there, read the  `product.asp?id=123` via Ajax and replace the HTML

But both are cumbersome and might not work if you need to `post` from the page

You can also use a [URL Rewriter](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) that does not change the browser URL (I have never used it, so can't recommend)

**My recommendation** is to stick with the old URL as long as you don't migrate them to MVC, and then perform the redirection from the old URL to the new one in `global.asax`

Comment: Thanks. I guess, I'll try to implement one of the free UrlRewriting components mentioned in the blog-posting behind your link.

Comment: Just now ScottGu have posted something new about Rewriting. Hope it helps. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx

Comment: It can be done using Server.TransferRequest on IIs7 with integrated pipeline mode. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Probably the simplest solution would be to use **Server.Transfer** which in contrast to **Response.Redirect** leaves the requested URL as it is.</strike>

I stand corrected: It is indeed not possible to Server.Transfer from a .aspx page to an .asp page.

---

It is however possible using **Server.TransferRequest** but it requires IIS7 with integrated pipeline mode.

**ASP.NET Placeholder Page**

```
<% Server.TransferRequest("Index.asp", true); %>
```

**ASP Target Page**

```
<%@ language="vbscript" %>
<% Response.Write(Request.QueryString("msg")) %>
```

**Usage**

```
http://yoursite/Index.aspx?msg=Hello%20World!
```

Comment: I think that you can't `Server.Transfer` to an ASP classic from a ASP.net page.